# Would (Dual Spool and Concentric Powerhead) FFSC Cycle engine be possible to engineer

Tags: propulsion, engine-design, design-alternative, engineering, plumbing

I,ve been wondering if it was possible engineer and how we would we work it out **DUAL SPOOL**  **FFSCC** ENGINE with concentric core and *individual* *concentric* turbine inside one another and maybe it could *advantageous* in design as; having the **FUEL-RICH** preburner coated specially to be placed internally the **lower oxygen preburner** manifold and, have a loop to guide gaseous fuel (**Hydrogen,methane,lng.etc**) into its manifold and the *gaseous oxygen* passes straight inline to its manifold like the *Raptor* engine does.

And the only benefit is that you would be able to fit more engines in a given area in the **launch vehicle base** and that the parts will be less. Second, disadvantage is that it would be slightly heavier and a more intricate system; but control wont a problem as, it will have **dual-spool concentric shafts**. and the (**HPFTP**)shaft will go bypass the **oxy-rich** **inline** manifold than in the ***oxygen preburner* body** than penetrate the **fuel rich inline preburner**, access the (**FTP**) and shaft axial bearings will be lubricated by fuel in the (Fuel Rich)**precombuster** manifold, so will the (HPOTP)shaft and bearings.

And i,m open o hear opinion and answers, it will very much be appreciated.
excuse me for some grammar errors

Comment: Is it single-shaft or dual-spool you are asking about? You mention both.

Comment: my bad its a dual spool concentric shaft

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify including the title.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.